# _Generic: suppress "error: undeclared (first use in this function)"

Tags: c, templates, generics, gcc, generic-programming

**code:**

```
int foo_i(int i) { return i; }

#define foo(type) _Generic((type), int: foo_i, float: foo_f)

int main(void) {
    int var1 = 42;
    int var2 = foo(var1);

    return 0;
}
```

**GCC error:**

```
error: ‘foo_f’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define foo(type) _Generic((type), int: foo_i, float: foo_f)
                                                       ^
note: in expansion of macro ‘foo’
  int var2 = foo(var1);
             ^~~
note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 #define foo(type) _Generic((type), int: foo_i, float: foo_f)
                                                       ^
note: in expansion of macro ‘foo’
  int var2 = foo(var1);
             ^~~
```

**Question:**

In my particular use case some functions, such as `foo_f` might not be declared, and that's OK because they are not going to be selected anyway. In the example above for instance, `foo_f` is never selected in my source, only `foo_i` is. How can I ask GCC to not raise an error in this situation but only if/when an undeclared function is actually selected? In other words I'd like GCC to only give me an error in this case

```
float var1 = 42;
int   var2 = foo(var1);
```

but **not** in this case

```
int var1 = 42;
int var2 = foo(var1);
```

Comment: Each branch of a `_Generic` has to be valid, even if it's not used.

Comment: It's similar to how `if` and `else` works. Even if the condition is true and the `else` branch doesn't execute, it must still contain valid code, including declarations of all symbols.

Comment: But if..else is processed at run time, _Generic is evaluated at compile time. This is what I don't understand, ie. why the compiler can't simply replace `foo` with `foo_i`.

Comment: `if` and `else` are *executed* at run-time, but the code is still *compiled* by the compiler at compile-time. The same thing that happens with `_Generic`, the code is compiled by the compiler, and all "branches" must be compilable.

Comment: Does _Generic create more branching code like if..else? Doesn't it work by performing text substitution like macros?

Comment: *Doesn't it work by performing text substitution like macros* No. Macro substitution happens at an earlier stage of compilation.

Comment: @Shawn So basically _Generic adds code to the final binary? That is something like "if type is int jump to 0xAAAA otherwise jump to 0xBBBB"?

Comment: If you're familiar with C++, it's kind of like a constexpr if. Evaluated at compile time and only one of the expressions is used, but since it's compile time, they all have to be valid.

Comment: Thanks, the example with `constexpr if` makes sense. I thought it would work by text substitution like macros. Having said that, since only part of the code is kept and the other is discarded, why can't compilers implement a more lax approach for example by not implementing any semantic analysis on the code that will be discarded anyway?

Comment: The problem lies in "foo_f might not be declared, and that's OK because they are not going to be selected anyway". If it's not going to be selected, it has no business being present in the `_Generic` list. Only include types explicitly supported in the list and let `default` handle those who aren't.

Comment: @Lundin Well I think for my use case that would be very useful behavior. In short, it's a small "header only" library with a generic template that is used as `#define TYPE int    \n    #include <..../library.h>` so the user can decide to define/declare the function only for a specific type. So it would be nice to have a _General function overload method that would select a function if it was defined, or ignore every other case.